# I am trying to animate with shape keys but it's not working

Tags: shape-keys

I have created 4 shape keys. When I raise the slider to 1 in frame 31 and 61 and back to zero on frames 1 and 101, keys are supposed to be set in those frames so an animation can be played. Nevertheless, nothing happens. What I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Link to the file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2660" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2660/)

Comment: Did you explicitly keyframe the value? Just changing the slider value alone doesn't automatically key frame the property, you have to explicitly press `i` to create the keyframe.

Comment: Thanks. I did (I-Key - Scaling in every frame marked: 1, 31, 61, 101) but nothing changed when I played the animation. As you might imagine, I am a beginner-beginner. I have attached a link to the file. Could you tell what I am missing?

Comment: I see nothing keyframed in your file. Just to be clear you have to set frame to [0] > Mouse cursor over the *Value* Slider > Press `i`> Slider will turn Green> Move timeline > (Slider will remain yellow) > Change *Value* Slider > Press `i`again , repeat for every animated frame